# Trouble with Lookup functions in AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-studio

Hope you're well and having a great day!

I'm working through a communication to our contacts that are experiencing shipping delays due to supply chain issues with our supplier. Though we're pulling our contact data from two Sales Cloud objects; `Opportunity` and `WorkOrder`. I've had to resolve an issue where the Opportunity (Classic sign-ups) contains a product code and name but not one we can surface to the customer (Product_Commercial_Name) which is present on the Work Order (our Lightning-based sign-ups). To get around this, I've created a reference Data Extension with the required SKU information which I was hoping to look up and print in the email i.e. `your %%=v(@incentiveName)%% is delayed...`

Here's my AMPscript:

```ampscript
%%[
var @classicIncentive, @productName, @incentiveName, @lightningSignUp

SET @lightningSignUp = WorkOrder_Id

IF EMPTY(@lightningSignUp) THEN
  SET @classicIncentive = '1'
ENDIF

IF @classicIncentive == '1' THEN
  SET @productName = Product_Commercial_Name__c
  SET @incentiveName = Lookup("Classic Incentive SKU Table","Product_Code","Product_Name",@productName)
ELSE 
  SET @incentiveName = Product_Commercial_Name__c
ENDIF]%%
```

The reference data extension contains three columns:

- `Product_Name`
- `Product_Code`
- `Product_Commercial_Name`

I was hoping to pul the `Product_Commercial_Name` value for Classic sign-ups. **BUT I'm having trouble getting my lookup function to work (it's probably just me being a newb).** I've reviewed the following resources to try to get it sorted but no luck just yet:

- [Salesforce Developer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm)
- [Sprignaturemoves](https://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/)
- [The AMPscript Guide](https://ampscript.guide/lookup/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the error you are recieving?

Comment: Hey @Gortonington, no validation errors, I was just unable to print the desired information into the email. Using Adam's script, I've been able to find and sort the error of my ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest adding some debugging output -- in addition to wrapping your personalization strings in [**AttributeValue**](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue).

```ampscript
%%[ 

SET @WorkOrder_Id = AttributeValue("WorkOrder_Id")

output(concat("<br>WorkOrder_Id: ", @WorkOrder_Id))

IF EMPTY(@WorkOrder_Id) THEN
  SET @classicIncentive = '1'
ENDIF

output(concat("<br>classicIncentive: ", @classicIncentive))

IF @classicIncentive == '1' THEN

  SET @productName = AttributeValue("Product_Commercial_Name__c")
  output(concat("<br>productName: ", @productName))

  SET @incentiveName = Lookup("Classic Incentive SKU Table","Product_Code","Product_Name", @productName)
ELSE 
  SET @incentiveName = AttributeValue("Product_Commercial_Name__c")
ENDIF

output(concat("<br>incentiveName: ", @incentiveName))

]%%
```

What output do you get if you add those statements?

Comment: Hey Adam, thank you for the above. Successfully returned the `Product_Code` using your script above. To get the desired field, I updated the look up to:  

`SET @incentiveName = Lookup("Classic Incentive SKU Table","Product_Commercial_Name","Product_Name", @productName)`

All working as expected now. Thank you very much for your help here.